# Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. Finding origin of issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Received the following error and I am not sure how to figure out where the problem originated:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extremely quick fix to this somewhat vague error which will give you a full stack trace with the offending component. Just put the following code into your console and attempt to recreate the error:

```
 var warn = console.warn;
  console.warn = function(warning) {
    if (/(setState)/.test(warning)) {
      throw new Error(warning);
    }
    warn.apply(console, arguments);
  };
```

This gives you the full stack trace. This can also be used for other warning messages by adjusting `(/(setState)/` to whatever error you want.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, the full stack trace should contain the offending line, just expand it and move up in the stack a bit.

Btw, React is very annoying with all its hand holding and this warning can actually be ignored. I mean, you want to fix it because it pollutes your console, but that's it.